# Batch zip multiple files with similar names

Tags: batch, zip, 7-zip

I have folder with number of files that are name the same but with different extensions.

I want to batch zip the same file name into same name.zip file.
Explain start files:

```
Seth.dbf  
Seth.prj  
Seth.shp  
Seth.shx  
Go to zip:  
Seth.zip
```

Files are located at `"C:\Batch"`
I am ok if the zip are located in the same folder as were the files are located.
I have used :

```
@ECHO OFF
set $PATH="C:Batch\"
pushd %$path%
FOR %%F IN (*.dbj) DO 7Z a "%%~nF.zip" "%%~nF.dbf" "%%~nF.prj"  "%%~nF.shp" "%%~nF.shx"
popd
Echo Done !!!
```

Or:

```
@ECHO OFF
PATH=C:\Batch
for %%e in ("*.dbj") do (%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe a "%%~ne.zip" "%%~ne.dbj" "%%~ne.prj" "%%~ne.shp" "%%~ne.shx")
```

I pasted the text into notepad and saved them as .bat files. Click on the bat file.
Both code didn't made any zip folders.
I didn't need to use both command just one that works. I could use the help understanding what I did wrong in the coding. Thanks

Comment: you are making this way to complicated. at least with 7zip, there is no need for a loop, and remember you can access all files named `seth` with any extension using `seth.*`. see here for basically an example of the single command required. https://7ziphelp.com/7zip-command-line#Archive_and_Add_to_ZIP

Comment: I have number of different files that have different names, but the same four ending extensions.  I would like it to zip for group of each of the ".dbf". I didn't want to have to type in the file names in the command. I want it to find the different file names and credit zip for each file name.  Explain 
Seth.dbf  Seth.prj
Seth.shp
Seth.shx to Seth.zip
Jon.dbf
Jon.prj
Jon.shp
Jon.shx  to Jon.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it is this that you want, this batch file can be set up to keep the original files or delete the original files. You have to drag and drop the source folder to the batch....

[DeleteOriginals.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP7P7.gif)

[KeepOriginals.gif](https://i.imgur.com/w1LOvjj.gif)

```
@echo off

:: Put the path to command line 7zip here:
set Seven=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

:: Delete original files "y" or "n"
set DOriginal=n
 
If exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Folder=%~1"
pushd "%Folder%"

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.*') do IF not "%%~na"=="!OldName!" (
                                                                       set /a Counter+=1
                                                                       set "NameArray[!Counter!]=%%~na"
                                                                       set "OldName=%%~na"
                                                                      )

If /i "%DOriginal%"=="y" (goto :Delete) else (goto :Keep)

:Delete
For /L %%a in (1,1,%Counter%) do "%Seven%" a -tzip -sdel "!NameArray[%%a]!.zip" *"!NameArray[%%a]!"*
goto :End

:Keep
For /L %%a in (1,1,%Counter%) do "%Seven%" a -tzip "!NameArray[%%a]!.zip" *"!NameArray[%%a]!"*
goto :End

:End
echo  Bye
exit
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I liked the gifs to show how it works. I was not drag the file to the dat file. It works as I planned.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as answer or click on arrow up?